# Hosted tile layer's pop-up won't work in AGOL web map

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service, arcgis-online-webmap, tile-layer

Upon opening one of my web maps I realized that the tile layers used in this map no longer display their pop-ups. These pop-ups were given to the tile layers from feature (polygon) layers. When trying to configure the tile layers' pop-ups all appears fine. This was not an issue till recently, and the web map operated as intended. Has a recent update caused this bug, or could this be something on my side?

Comment: can you share the web map? Is the feature layer still accessible?

Comment: https://arcg.is/1TKm8r here is the map. The pop-up works fine for the feature layer and i can access it as usual in my content.

Comment: The pop-up is supposed to also appear for the orthophotos and hillshade tile layers but unfortunately it does not.

Comment: I think the issue is the scale range for the feature layer. If you zoom out(adjust the issue hillshade scale range) so that it matches the scale you are trying to get the popup at and it seems to return the popup.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You mean i have to set the feature layers visibility range to match that of the tiles? If so this is not what i'd prefer to do since i'd like the polygons to disappear when (upon zooming in) the tiles appear. This all used to work fine a week ago. The setup was the same and the pop-ups for the tiles worked as intended. This leads me to think it might be a bug .

Comment: I actually figured it out based on your last comment. The issue was that the visibility range had been changed in the feature layer's visibility tab in it's item page. This did not affect it's visibility range in the web map, as i have manually set it inside the map, but caused the pop-up for the tile packages to not appear beyond the range set in the service's item page. Thank you.